# Is there a passive benefit of "Deflector Dish" and similar stats in Star Trek online?

Tags: star-trek-online

There are several stats (Deflector Dish, Deflector Field, Emitters, etc) that you can have on your Deflector Array.

Do these stats have any passive effect?

Any effect at all other than increasing the strength of specific Bridge Officer abilities?

Comment: Minor distinction: In addition to your Bridge Officers' abilities, it also affects YOUR abilities, presuming you have abilities which makes use of those stats. (ie, you're a Science Officer)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Star Trek Online Wiki](http://www.stowiki.org/Deflector_Dish):

> Modifiers
>
> Some Deflector Dishes may have
>   additional modifiers that boost
>   various skills. It is possible for a
>   Deflector Dish to have the same
>   modifier more than once. The following
>   are examples of Deflector Dish
>   modifiers.
>
> ```
> Modifier  Skill Boost
> [Ast]        +10 Astrometrics
> [Def]        +10 Starship Deflectors
> [DefD]       +10 Starship Deflector Dish
> [DefF]       +10 Starship Deflector Field
> [EM]         +10 Starship Emitters
> [HS]         +10 Starship Hazard System
> [Sen]        +10 Starship Sensors
> [SenA]       +10 Starship Sensor Array
> [SenP]       +10 Starship Sensor Probes
> [Spa]        +10 Spatial Anomaly
> [ST]         +10 Photonic Theory
> [TB]         +10 Starship Tractor Beam
> ```
>
> Uncommon deflector arrays will have
>   one modifier, Rare will have two, and
>   Very Rare will have three.

---

So yes, modifiers active as passive effects. Furthermore each type of deflector dish(Deflector Array, Graviton Deflector Array, Positron Deflector Array, Tachyon Deflector Array) give different boosts to your starship.

Comment: Also, if you select "Info" for the item, the description is remarkably elaborate on exactly that the various bonuses affect. For deflectors in particular, it goes into good detail on not only what they do, but what general type of player would want it.